# HttpClient Post without FormUrlEncodedContent

Tags: post, httpclient, urlencode

I am using HTTPClient to make a post request, following is the simple code.

```
private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();     
var values = new Dictionary<string, string>{
                { "x", "value" }};
var content  = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
var response = await client.PostAsync(someUrl, content);
```

If I dont want to use FormUrlEncodedContent, what are the other alternatives to post data? i.e. I dont want to url encode my post body.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have data in your model format.. E.g., `UserData` then you could try:

```
UserData ud = new UserData(){
// your user's data here
};

var content = new ObjectContent<UserData>(ud , new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());

var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
```

Would this work?